# How to get a invisible series data value in callback

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Take the following csv data for example,

```
Index,Time,Value
0,2021/7/30 16:25:09.408,-74.63
1,2021/7/30 16:25:09.421,-75.25
2,2021/7/30 16:25:09.621,-76.13
3,2021/7/30 16:25:09.821,-76.19
```

I want to get the Index series when user clicks the chart or point, but index is not expected to show in chart.

I tried to set Index series as invisible with "visibility" option, but it was also not able to get the index value in callback function.

Is there any method to not show in chart but get the value in callback ?

Thanks~

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to resolve this question:
the callback will give "point" and there is an idx in it.

Since Index may not equal to point.idx (which are selected from source csv), I save a mapping between Index and point.idx when generate the chart csv.

So, get the index value as click -> point -> point.idx -> Index.